# How does CALL ETIME(X) work?

Tags: fortran

the syntax of ETIME is like `CALL ETIME(VALUES, TIME)` 
I saw a code which uses `Call ETIME(PP)` and it does not use implicit none.
Why does it work and what is PP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etime is not a standard intrinsic function. Every compiler implements is as they wish. For example in gfortran you can use both:

```
CALL ETIME(VALUES, TIME)
TIME = ETIME(VALUES)      ! (not recommended)
```

`implicit none` does not influence intrinsic functions, both standard and non-standard. You can signify the fact that it is an intrinsic by using the `intrinsic` statement to distinguish from some external function.

Standard alternatives are `system_clock()` and `cpu_time()`.

---

What is `PP`? Who knows, you must look in the code where you saw it. It is an argument of the subroutine, but maybe it was the function form when you saw it?

Comment: What is PP: it is not used before this call.

Comment: In that cast it is a real variable declared implicitly. But really, we do not know what is it, author of that code must know that.